# Ag-grid hide tool panel

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I would like to start the ag-grid with collapsed tool panel.

The grid should show like this: [image]

Can some one explain how to do this ?

Comment: What version? The side panel is not rendered by default from v19... What do your grid options look like

Comment: ag-grid-enterprise v21.0.1 this is information on ag-grid-entrerpreise.js

Comment: Let me correct some information from my question. I want to start the grid in mode collapsed only. Same as the image.

Answer (score 2):

You hide it by setting defaultToolPanel to null or empty string

```js
public sideBar = {
  toolPanels: [
    {
      id: 'columns',
      labelDefault: 'Columns',
      labelKey: 'columns',
      iconKey: 'columns',
      toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
      toolPanelParams: {
        suppressRowGroups: true,
        suppressValues: true,
        suppressPivots: true,
        suppressPivotMode: true,
        suppressSideButtons: true,
        suppressColumnFilter: true,
        suppressColumnSelectAll: true,
        suppressColumnExpandAll: true
      }
    }
  ],
  defaultToolPanel: ''
};
```

Comment: This answer works for ag-grid 25.3.0

Comment: Thank you! This works and I believe it should be set as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Provide the configuration in aggrid.

```
***sideBar = false***
```

To use the default sidebar, set the grid property sideBar=true. The Columns panel will be open by default

```
<AgGridReact
   defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
   animateRows={true}
   sideBar={false}
/>
```

Comment: This is not making the toolpannel hiding by default

Comment: We should provide a value to sideBar like done by the other answer, please consider removing your answer.